# Adjusting LDA hyperparameters in SciKit learn or Gensim (Python 3)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, gensim, hyperparameters

I am experimenting with topic modelling in Gensim and SciKit learn (Python 3) and would like to know more about adjusting hyperparamters in either package.

I found some related discussions on GITHUB, e.g. ["optimize hyperparameters as part of LDA training"](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/105), but no complete documentation.

I am not even sure hyperparametre optimisation is at all possible in SciKit learn.

I am very grateful for links or book recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link for the different hyperparameters of LDA

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html

You can try using GridSearch or RandomSearch for hypertuning